# How I can check if user liked video on youtube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to check, this user placed like or no, how I can do this? ty for answer

Comment: By user you mean an account you own or not ? And what videos are you talking about ? Videos that you own ? If both answers are no, then for sure you can't access such data for privacy reasons.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison I mean, how do I check if a user has liked MY video. For example, I know a user account (for example, John) and I want to see if John liked my video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is out of scope for the YouTube api.  There is no way to see who has liked a specific video.  Even if you could the user who did the liking would have to have been the one to authenticate the application granting you access to this kind of data.

the best you can see when you login is how many likes your video has, you cant even see what videos you have personally liked.